# JavaFX - How to clear all the nodes from an anchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using sceneBuilder.

> How to clear an AnchorPane ? 
>  Is there a way to delete all the
>   nodes contained in an AnchorPane (already created from sceneBuilder and populated with buttons and shapes) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nodes of an AnchorPane are in a list. So you could do this:

```
myPane.getChildren().clear();
```